# Quando converter um bitmap para string base64?

Tags: base64

Eu sei que, antigamente, era necessário converter uma imagem para string, [por causa de limitações com o SMTP](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Introdu.C3.A7.C3.A3o).

Minhas dúvidas são:

- Qual a utilidade dessa prática atualmente?
- Existe algum ganho em termos de desempenho em relação a armazenar/transmitir dados binários em seus formatos originais (nesse caso, bitmap)?
- Quando armazenadas localmente, devemos utilizar bitmap ou string base64?
- Quando é uma boa prática utilizar bitmap? E string base64?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) é uma forma de escrever um vetor de bytes qualquer usando só letras e números (e mais uns dois ou três símbolos). Vale notar que base64 não é um padrão universal mas sim uma família de codificações semelhantes: a maioria concorda em usar A-Z, a-z e 0-9 como 62 dos 64 símbolos da codificação mas há uma certa variação sobre os dois últimos caracteres usar, qual o valor numérico atribuído para cada símbolo e como escrever o padding caso a mensagem a ser codificada não tenha um número de bytes múltiplo de 3.

### Qual a utilidade dessa prática atualmente?

Às vezes você precisa incluir dados binários em algum lugar que só aceita caracteres ASCII. Além do exemplo de email que você já mencionou:

- [Embutir um ícones codificados com base64](http://davidwalsh.name/blank-favicon) dentro de um arquivo HTML, Javascript ou CSS.
- Nomes de arquivos
- URLs (por exemplo, aquelas letrinhas em um URL abreviado pelo twitter)

### Quando armazenadas localmente, devemos utilizar bitmap ou string base64?

Se possível, armazene os dados no formato original. Você gasta menos espaço (cada grupo de três bytes é codificado usando 4 bytes em base64) e não precisa se preocupar com ficar codificando e decodificando os dados o tempo todo.

### Existe algum ganho em termos de desempenho em relação a armazenar/transmitir dados binários em seus formatos originais (nesse caso, bitmap)?

Em geral, ao usar base 64 você paga um preço de performance (cada 3 bytes do arquivo original são codificados usando 4 bytes ASCII) em troca de poder escrever seus dados em um lugar que não aceitaria os dados binários diretamente.

Codificar os dados só tem como ganhar performance indiretamente. Por exemplo, no caso do favicon, o preço de embutir os dados em base64 pode ser menor que o preço de uma request HTTP extra para pegar o arquivo binário separadamente. No caso dos URLs, base64 pode ser usado para escrever números de forma compacta: da mesma forma que números escritos em hexadecimal tem menos dígitos que o equivalente decimal, números em base 64 ou base 62 são ainda mais compactos. Por exemplo, o 32695 no url dessa pergunta poderia ser escrito como "3-H" = 3*64<sup>2</sup> + 62*64<sup>1</sup> + 55.

Answer (score 1):

> Qual a utilidade dessa prática atualmente?

**Portabilidade**. Em alguns casos você precisa garantir que o recurso estará disponível em qualquer situação: Se seu conteúdo HTML está sendo gerado dinamicamente em modo offline, sem acesso à internet ou operando em um protocolo (HTTPS por exemplo) que não lhe permite acessar recursos em modo híbrido.

Um exemplo são os [Chrome URLs](http://www.ghacks.net/2012/09/04/list-of-chrome-urls-and-their-purpose/), onde todas as imagens presentes são base64:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Teste algumas destas URLs no Chrome:

chrome://ipc
chrome://inspect
chrome://media-internals
chrome://memory

> Existe algum ganho em termos de desempenho em relação a
>   armazenar/transmitir dados binários em seus formatos originais (nesse
>   caso, bitmap)?

Na prática, **a diferença é negligível**. Uma vez que seu conteúdo esteja armazenado em cache, ele é tratado da mesma maneira pelos browsers modernos, seja sua origem uma resposta a um `GET` ou interpretação de conteúdo *inline* base64.

(Vale mencionar que se você estiver embutindo conteúdo base64 em uma página gerada dinamicamente você estará reenviando o conteúdo a cada requisição.)

> Quando armazenadas localmente, devemos utilizar bitmap ou string
>   base64?

Se por localmente você quer dizer o navegador, não existe razão para se preocupar com isso.

Caso você queira dizer o servidor, isso depende da sua estratégia de implementação; lembre-se que *toda* alteração do arquivo atômico (contendo HTML/CSS + base64) implicará em um **flush/refresh do cache**.

> Quando é uma boa prática utilizar bitmap? E string base64?

Os formatos binários mais utilizados (JPEG, PNG) utilizam menos bytes do que uma string base64, mas essa diferença só é sentida em um acesso com o cache ainda vazio.

Se você está armazenando uma **grande quantidade de imagens** ou visualizando apenas um pequeno set da coleção, utilize arquivos binários.

Se sua aplicação utiliza poucos gráficos bitmap ou precisa rodar em **modo offline**, base64.